# Java. Печать из Excel

Tags: java, excel, печать, apache-poi

Суть задачи в следующем:
Есть 2 xls-файла. В первом содержится выборка данных из БД, а второй предназначен для ручного ввода данных из первого файла. Ячейки во втором файле растянуты до нужных размеров, чтобы печать была корректной на нестандартной бумаге (по сути второй файл - просто шаблон для печати (поменяли данные вручную, распечатали и так по кругу)).

С помощью библиотеки `org.apache.poi`, я достаю нужные данные из первого файла.

- Возможно ли эти данные распечатывать в обход файла-шаблона (задавать
  тексту нужные отступы и размеры шрифта)?
- Или может есть способ эти данные вставлять в шаблон и сразу пускать
  на печать в фоне (чтобы пользователю не приходилось открывать
  измененный документ Excel каждый раз при печати)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обо всём по порядку.

> Возможно ли эти данные распечатывать в обход файла-шаблона (задавать
>   тексту нужные отступы и размеры шрифта)?

Да, возможно. Java поддерживает работу с принтером.

> Или может есть способ эти данные вставлять в шаблон и сразу пускать на
>   печать в фоне (чтобы пользователю не приходилось открывать измененный
>   документ Excel каждый раз при печати)?

Как один из возможных вариантов. Создать на основе шаблона временный файл, вывести его на печать и после удалить. Apache-poi поддерживает не только чтение из Excel, но и запись.

Подробно описывать процесс не стану, т.к. он хорошо документирован. В частности есть даже [подробная переводная инструкция](https://tproger.ru/translations/how-to-read-write-excel-file-java-poi-example/) на эту тему.

Что касается вывода на печать. Самый простой способ, вывести файл средствами Excel или какого-нибудь OpenOffice на принтер по умолчанию.

```
Desktop.getDesktop().print(new File(file_path));
```

Печать будет выполнена в фоне.

Если требуются дополнительные настройки, то здесь уже надо смотреть по ситуации.

Comment: С помощью этой инструкции я вставлял данные во второй файл. А как его пустить на печать в фоне? Спасибо

Comment: Это зависит от контекста. Под Windows вполне можно вывести на печать средствами Excel или какого-нибудь OpenOfiice. Под *nix с ходу не могу сказать.

Comment: использование предполагается только под Windows

Comment: Под Windows, если установлен офисный пакет, можно решить эту задачу при помощи метода  `print` класса `Desktop`.

Comment: Уже решил с помощью отдельного `vbs-скрипта`, но думаю Ваш ответ будет гораздо удобнее, спасибо!